# What happens to the Black Blade of a slain Magus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

My party has just killed a Bladebound Magus.

What will happen to the Black Blade?

- Can we take the blade?
- What would be the requirements for wielding it?
- Can we sell it? and if so, how would we calculate its value?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Bladebound](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo-magus-archetypes/bladebound/) is similar to a familiar, only granting bonuses to a magus with the bladebound archetype. It says:

> A black blade has special abilities (or imparts abilities to its wielder) depending on the wielder’s magus level. The abilities are cumulative. A black blade normally **refuses to use any of its abilities when wielded by anyone other than its magus, and acts as a masterwork weapon** of its type.

So, in the hands of everybody else, it is merely a masterwork weapon. The sword doesn't care much about who the owner is, as long as you have levels in the magus class with the bladebound archetype.

The black blade has it's own flavor with it's own agenda, which is unrelated to it's current owner. If *another* magus were to pick it up, they would work as their own bound black blade. So, all you need to be able to use your recently acquired black blade is to take a single level on the magus (bladebound) class, and upon reaching 3rd level, you may declare it is yours.

> A black blade is independently conscious but features some personality traits reflecting its wielder. A black blade always has the same alignment as its wielder and even changes its alignment if its wielder does. The blade typically works toward its wielder’s goals, but not always without argument or backlash.
>
> Each black blade has a mission, and while sometimes two or more black blades will work in concert, each mission is singular in purpose (the black blade’s mission is usually up to the GM and the needs of the campaign or the adventure, or a GM can determine the weapon’s purpose randomly using Table: Intelligent Item Purpose). Some black blades are very open about their missions, but most are secretive.
>
> Certain sages have speculated that an invisible hand or arcane purpose moves these weapons.

Anyone can wield it, it is a masterwork blade of its type. But you must have 3 levels of Bladebound Magus to unlock its magical powers.

And should your group decide to sell it, it should be evaluated as a masterwork weapon (+300 gp) of it's type. If it's a longsword, 308 gp. If it's a rapier, 320 gp. If it's a sword-cane, 345 gp. And so on. The magical abilities only matter for an aspiring soon-to-be bladebound magus, but mechanically the sword grants no benefit to anyone else.

Comment: Could this answer include an example of a way that a black blade could be convinced to use its abilities on behalf of a new owner?

Comment: It only works in the hands of another bladebound magus.

Comment: How do you get "doesn't care much about who the owner is" from "when wielded by anyone other than *its* magus"?

Comment: @Ifusaso because that's their flavor, read the entire archetype. As long as a magus (*any* magus) is wielding the black blade, it will try to fulfil it's mysterious destiny.

Comment: I still disagree. The only reference to actually being able to wield another's Black Blade is if it's inherited as part of taking the archetype... usually because the Black Blade *chose you* or you literally inherited it from your lineage. To counter this simple flavor implication, there are numerous content locations that reference "A black blade is bonded to a particular magus..." and similar

Comment: *"There are several ways a magus might gain this weapon. "* The examples are merely examples, obtaining the blade from a deceased enemy magus is just as valid as all other methods.

Comment: Including: *"Other times the magus finds a black blade during an adventure or event of some kind."*